# How can I wrap with a range of numbers?

Tags: javascript, numbers, line-breaks

I'd want to know how can I break the line when my list of numbers reach 10 and his multiples until 100. 
 Example: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
... 
This is what I wrote so far

```
var limit= 100;
var str= "";

for (var i =1; i<=limit; i++){
str += i+ "";
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: In what context? Console output? A web page? Something else?

Comment: In a console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as well :

```js
var limit= 100;
var str= "";

for (var i = 1; i <= limit; ++i) {
    str += i + ((i % 10) ? " " : "\n");
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @JacopoGiurgevich - Just so you know, this is exactly what I did in my answer, just applied via a conditional operator rather than an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remainder operator (`%`) to determine whether `i` is a multiple of 10 like this:

```
if (i % 10 === 0) {
    // Yes, it is
}
```

Note that `0` will also match that, but you're starting from `1` so you're okay.

So in your loop, just after¹ outputting the item, use that to output a newline (whatever a newline is in the environment you're using). For instance (I added spaces between the numbers for clarity):

```js
var limit= 100;
var str= "";

for (var i = 1; i <= limit; ++i) {
    str += i + " ";
    if (i % 10 === 0) {
        str += "\n";
    }
}
console.log(str);
```

---

¹ It's *after* because you started with `1`. If you started with `0`, it would be before (and you'd need `i !== 0 &&` on the check).

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work: in the chrome's console it output: 1 <br>
1 2 <br>
1 2 3 <br>
1 2 3 4 <br>
1 2 3 4 5 <br>
...

Comment: @JacopoGiurgevich - All due respect, you must not have done it as above, since the runnable example in the above works just fine.

Comment: Yes, probably I did something wrong, I'm almost a total beginner, but I find a little clearer the answer of Pranav Rustagi. Doesn't mean I'm not thankful to you or I don't recognize the importance of your advices.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '';

for(let i =0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  const isWrap = (i > 0) && (i % 10 === 0);
  
  str += isWrap ? '\n' : ' ';
  str += (i+1);
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine, using Array.from to make the array and map to chunk it (slice could be used  to chunk too)

```js
const makeGrid = lim => Array.from(Array(lim+1).keys()) // make 101
  .slice(1) // drop the 0
  .map(i => i%10===0?` ${i}\n`:` ${i}`) // map to have a newline
  .join("");
console.log(makeGrid(100));
```